# poor performance of my crawlspider following links conditional on page-text

Tags: scrapy

I am using a crawlspider to follow links only if a page contains some key words. In general this works but the performance is poor. Main parts of the code are:

class CrawlSpider_PlainVanilla(CrawlSpider):

```
name = "my_crawlspider"

rules = (Rule(link_extractor=None,callback='parse_link', follow=True, process_request='filter_response'),)
```

and

```
def filter_response(self, request, response):
    my_body = response.xpath(self.my_str).re(self.my_reg)
    if my_body != []:
        return request
```

where self.my_str is a xpath selector (excluding elements like meta or script) and self.my_reg is a regular expression. The rest of the code is standard. The strange thing is, that I have implemented the same stuff with a standard scrapy.Spider and here the performance is quite good. I would appreciate any hint concerning drawbacks of my code.

Best regards

Gerd